# Using a fallback value from a table with PDO bound parameters/values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In a particular method I need a fallback to a particular piece of data in a table if a variable isn't given. Something that looks like this:

```
public function readDiscountsForCampaign(CD\Campaign $oCampaign, $iPricelistId = 0) {
  // do stuff
}
```

So if `$iPricelistId === 0` I want the SQL query to retrieve the pricelist from `channel.default_pricelist_id` instead.

With PDO prepared statements you obviously can't bind tables names to parameters or values so there are really only 2 options.

1: interpolate the value into the query string, like:

```
public function readDiscountsForCampaign(CD\Campaign $oCampaign, $iPricelistId = 0) {

  //ensure the pricelist id is an integer
  $iPricelistId = (int) $iPricelistId;

  //create the string to insert into the SQL query string
  $sPricelistInsert = $iPricelistId ? $iPricelistId : "channel.default_pricelist_id";

  //SQL query string
  $sQuery = "SELECT ... all the select stuff here "
          . "WHERE pricelist.pricelist_id = {$sPricelistInsert}"; // <-- which will be either the (int) or channel.default_pricelist_id

  // do other stuff, run the query and return

}
```

2: Use an SQL IF on the WHERE condition

```
public function readDiscountsForCampaign(CD\Campaign $oCampaign, $iPricelistId = 0) {

  //ensure the pricelist id is an integer
  $iPricelistId = (int) $iPricelistId;

  //SQL query string
  $sQuery = "SELECT ... all the select stuff here "
          . "WHERE pricelist.pricelist_id = IF(:pricelist_id > 0, :pricelist_id, channel.default_pricelist_id)";

  //bind ':pricelist_id' to $iPricelistId for the prepared statement
  $aBoundValues = array(':pricelist_id' => $iPricelistId);

  // then do other stuff, run the query and return

}
```

---- edit : updated to include Tadman's 3rd option ----

3: build the query sequentially and bind the pricelist_id if required (generally speaking this will be better than option 1 as no interpolation of values is required)

```
public function readDiscountsForCampaign(CD\Campaign $oCampaign, $iPricelistId = 0) {

  //create an array of bound parameters/values
  $aBoundValues = array();

  //ensure the pricelist id is an integer
  $iPricelistId = (int) $iPricelistId;

  //SQL query string
  $sQuery = "SELECT ... all the select stuff here "
          . "WHERE pricelist.pricelist_id = ";

  //if we have a pricelist id ...
  if($iPricelistId) {
    $sQuery .= ":pricelist_id";
    $aBoundValues[':pricelist_id'] = $iPricelistId;
  }

  // ... if not, fallback to the default from `channel`.`default_pricelist_id`
  else {
    $sQuery .= "channel.default_pricelist_id";
  }

  // do other stuff, run the query and return

}
```

---- end edit ----

Now, which of these is the better option..? I'd kinda like a reason why too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compose the query conditionally, then execute it with bound parameters. Don't use string substitution unless you literally have no other option, it's extremely risky.

For example, you can build up your query incrementally:

```
$sQuery = "SELECT ... WHERE pricelist.pricelist_id=";
$bind = array();

if (...) {
  $sQuery .= ":pricelist_id";
  $bind[':pricelist_id'] = $pricelist_id;
} else {
  $sQuery .= "channel.default_pricelist_id";
}
```

Then you can execute with the `$bind` array as the values.

Comment: That would work but is it better than simply having the `IF` statement inside the SQL query (as in the 2nd example) - which doesn't require any sequential query building and has `$iPricelistId` bound to ':pricelist_id'? And unless I'm missing something there shouldn't be much of a risk with interpolating the `pricelist_id` in this instance as it's cast to an integer beforehand (as in the first example)..?

Comment: It's the application code's job to generate the query it wants, and the database to execute it. Passing the buck to the database for this kind of decision is sloppy, and if you continue this pattern you'll have quite a mess on your hands. Remember, composing more needlessly complicated queries creates load on the shared database resource and impacts other parts of your system and is usually a bad idea. The third version you've posted is the most concise from the database perspective and is the best in my opinion.

Comment: Thanky! Gives me a logical reason on how to proceed which is sort of what I was after... I can always solve problems but it's then solving my solutions to those problems where I sometimes fall short ;)